# is there a way to make DOMElement.attributes list clean(standard) in older internet explorers?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

as in subject

Element.attributes array contents will blow your mind in internet explorer 6-7-8

actually this getter returns the entire properties list of the javascript Object

there's a way to emulate the standard way in older IE browsers?

feel free to correct my english. thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to list all the attributes of a DOM Element in IE ?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to do list attributes of a dom element in IE

Answer (score 1):

Since the browser turns o IE, I have some notices on the code below :

- Code will only list the attribute which has a certain value (not null). Unless, IE will list  all about more than 100 attributes for a single element. I think that's unnecessary.
- You'll get some more extra attributes like "tabindex","readOnly"... although your element code is just simple like : "`<input type=text>`". This is cause IE way to do it.

Well, the code will be something like this :

```
$(function(){
    var A = $('.targetElement').get(0).attributes
    try{
        var i=0;
        while(A.item(i)){
            if (A.item(i).value != '' && A.item(i).value != 'null'){
                $('body').append( A.item(i).name+ ' = '+ A.item(i).value + '<br>' )
            }
            i++
        }
    }catch(e){}
})
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand jquery, can you write this in a standard way? BTW I'm trying to list only attributes that are actually attached in the tag declaration... parsing the innerHTML would be better?

Comment: Sorry, but indeed I'm not familiar with writing JS code without jQuery. For your idea, I've got a plan : 1-getElement_HTMLCode >> 2-Analyze the code >> 3-Strip out the attribute. The hardest part, I think, is step 1.

Comment: To get the element's own HTMLCode - without jQuery- I think the line should be : get element --> clone it --> append it to a blank div --> get the div's innerHTML --> get the element tag out.

Comment: yes parse a cloneNode(false) would be sufficiently fast because clean of any contents